# VBA Display multiple instances of bad characters in a worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I was given a chunk of code used to identify double quotes etc. in an excel worksheet. The present code shows one instance of a double quote in a message box and I'm trying to get it to display all instances. Below is an excerpt from what I was given. I added .address to the variable to give an exact address, but it shows only one. I tried to repeat the variable hoping to display multiple instances of the quote, but no luck so far.

```
Option Explicit
Sub BadCHARFinder()


'Finds any occurance of: Quotes (single or double, Underscore, Hyphen, Carot in the excel sheet
'Note: skips the header row when searching

'Find Double Quote (")

Dim foundDoubleQuote As Variant

Set foundDoubleQuote = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find("""", ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 1), xlValues, xlPart)

If (Not foundDoubleQuote Is Nothing) Then

    'found
    MsgBox "Found double quote at: " & foundDoubleQuote.Address, vbOKOnly, "foundDoubleQuote"
Else

    'not found

End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve - just list the addresses or remove them?

Answer (score 2):

You need to Find the next one right so Range.FindNext is what you are looking for.  below is how you can loop and grab all the addresses

```
Option Explicit
Sub BadCHARFinder()


'Finds any occurance of: Quotes (single or double, Underscore, Hyphen, Carot in the excel sheet
'Note: skips the header row when searching

'Find Double Quote (")

Dim foundDoubleQuote As Variant
Dim allCellAddresses As String
Dim firstCellAddress As String
Set foundDoubleQuote = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find("""", ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1), xlValues, xlPart, xlByRows)

    If (Not foundDoubleQuote Is Nothing) Then
        'capture the first cell address or we end up in an endless loop
        firstCellAddress = foundDoubleQuote.Address
        Do
            'add the address of the cell to our string of cells
            allCellAddresses = allCellAddresses + vbCrLf + foundDoubleQuote.Address
            'find the next cell with the data
            Set foundDoubleQuote = ActiveSheet.Cells.FindNext(foundDoubleQuote)
        'keep going until we find the first address we started with
        Loop While foundDoubleQuote.Address <> firstCellAddress
        'inform user
        MsgBox "Found double quote at: " & allCellAddresses, vbOKOnly, "foundDoubleQuote"
    Else

        'not found

    End If
End Sub
```